# Cycling through and previewing fonts in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

There's a trick I've seen other graphic designers do where they'll highlight a block of text, and then seemingly down-arrow through their whole list of fonts, seeing how it looks on that text block, 'til they find one that looks right. Yet when I try to emulate, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: With what software?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the Type Tool selected and click in the font name in the toolbar along the top to highlight it blue, then you can use your arrow key to go through the fonts.

[image]